# individually number visible elements in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some sections that contain boxes which need to be numbered sequentially, just like an ordered list (though, sadly, using OL is not an acceptable option). Each box can be manually hidden, and these hidden boxes need to be ignored when it comes to the count.

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
     <h1>List One</h1>
     <div class="box" style="display:none;"><!-- Ignored -->
        <span class="number"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="box">
        <span class="number"><!-- Want: 1 - Displays: 1 --></span>
     </div>
     <div class="box">
         <span class="number"><!-- Want: 2 - Displays: 2 --></span>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="section">
     <h1>List Two</h1>
     <div class="box">
        <span class="number"><!-- Want: 1 - Displays: 3 --></span>
     </div>
     <div class="box" style="display:none;"><!-- Ignored -->
        <span class="number"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="box">
        <span class="number"><!-- Want: 2 - Displays: 4 --></span>
     </div>    
</div>
```

CODE:

```
        $('.section').each(function(){

            var $section = $(this);

            $('.box:visible',this).each(function(){

                $('.number', this).text(

                    $(this).index('.box:visible') + 1

                );

            });

        });
```

The boxes in the first section number 1 and 2 correctly, but when it comes to the second section, it carries on, numbering those 3 and 4 instead of 1 and 2. I've figured out that it's because

```
$(this).index('.box:visible')
```

is getting the index of all visible boxes *relative to the page*, so how do I get the index of visible boxes relative to their parent only? I hoped it would be something like

```
$(this).index('.box:visible', $section)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you do something like

```
$(function () {
    $("div.section").each(function () {
        $(this).find("div.box:visible span.number").each(function (index) {
            $(this).html(index + 1);
        });
    });

});
```